# Serve image from link in Python with bottle webframework

Tags: javascript, python, html, bottle

I retrieve a link to an image from a webservice:

I can call:

```
http://webservice/getimage/34312
```

which will return the link to an image in the format:

```
http://www.server.com/image.jpg
```

So I only get the response in a string, no real image is returned.

I would like to show this image in a webpage. Something like:

```
<img src="http://webservice/getimage/34312" />
```

Of course this will not work, how do I do this right. Do I need javascript really?

Comment: What are these images? Are they static files on the machine or are you dynamically generating them?

Comment: they are dynamically created when the webservice is called